# Camera setDisplayOrientation() in Portrait Mode Breaks Aspect Ratio

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to get camera previews to work properly in portrait mode, where the activity itself is allowed to change orientation normally (i.e., not be locked to landscape).

The use of `setDisplayOrientation()` seriously breaks the behavior of the previews, though.

This can be demonstrated by Google's own ApiDemos. The first image is based on the `CameraPreview` from the `android-17` edition of the `ApiDemos` sample project, where the only change I made was to remove `android:orientation="landscape"` from this activity's entry in the manifest. The following image is a screenshot of what appears on the display of a Nexus 4, running Android 4.2, with the camera pointed at a 8.5" square of paper:

[image: Nexus 4 ApiDemos Preview, Portrait Mode]

What is not obvious from that preview is that it is rotated 90 degrees. The sock-clad feet that you see on the far right of the image were actually below the square.

The solution for this, at least for landscape mode, is to use `setDisplayOrientation()`. But, if you modify the `Preview` inner class of `CameraPreview` to have `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);`, you get this:

[image: Nexus 4 ApiDemos Preview, Portrait Mode, with setDisplayOrientation(90)]

Notably, the square is no longer square.

This uses the same `SurfaceView` size as before. I have reproduced this scenario with some other code, outside of `ApiDemos`, and I get the same behavior with `TextureView` in that code.

I thought briefly that the issue might be that `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` might return different values based upon `setDisplayOrientation()`, but a quick test suggests that this is not the case.

Anyone have any idea how to get `setDisplayOrientation()` to work in portrait mode without wrecking the aspect ratio of the imagery pushed over to the preview?

Thanks!

Comment: i find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710573/camera-display-doesnt-maintain-aspect-ratio-seems-skewed   tell me if it is, i will write a full answer

Comment: @idan: Sorry, but there is no action bar on `CameraPreview` in the `ApiDemos`. It already uses `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE`. Thanks, though!

Comment: I've been working on this a lot myself recently. One thing to keep in mind (and maybe you already are) is that the preview sizes do not swap dimensions when you rotate to portrait. If the default camera orientation is landscape, the width will be the width of the phone in landscape, regardless of whether you're actually *in* landscape, so you may have to reverse the width/height parameters when you're checking for the correct preview size.

Comment: @kcoppock: Well, something in how you phrased that helped a bit. I had seen that comment before, but I thought it meant reversing the height/width for `setPreviewSize()`, which doesn't work (unless the reversed size happens to be a valid preview size). However, by reversing the height/width of the preview `View` itself (e.g., `SurfaceView`), I get a fair bit closer to the proper aspect ratio. It's not yet accurate, but it's not as egregious as what I show above. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Setting up a camera preview is way more complicated than it should be (probably why most barcode scanner apps seem to lock in landscape). There's also the issue that you don't get an onCreate/onDestroy event when going from landscape to reverse landscape, so you end up with an upside-down preview in that case, which I haven't found a (non-hackish) solution for as of yet. If you do find a solid solution for this aspect ratio issue, I'd love to hear it. Good luck!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, I think that I figured this out. There were a few pieces to the proverbial puzzle, and I thank @kcoppock for the insight that helped me solve some of this.

First, you need to take the orientation into account when determining what preview size to choose. For example, the `getOptimalPreviewSize()` from the `CameraPreview` of `ApiDemos` is oblivious to orientation, simply because their version of that app has the orientation locked to landscape. If you wish to let the orientation float, you need to reverse the target aspect ratio to match. So, where `getOptimalPreviewSize()` has:

```
double targetRatio=(double)width / height;
```

you also need:

```
if (displayOrientation == 90 || displayOrientation == 270) {
  targetRatio=(double)height / width;
}
```

where `displayOrientation` is a value from 0 to 360, that I am determining from about 100 lines of some *seriously* ugly code, which is why I am wrapping all of this up in a reusable component that I'll publish shortly. That code is based on [the `setDisplayOrientation()` JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29) and [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383164/115145).

(BTW, if you are reading this after 1 July 2013, and you don't see a link in this answer to that component, post a comment to remind me, as I forgot)

Second, you need to take that display orientation into account when controlling the aspect ratio of the `SurfaceView`/`TextureView` that you are using. The `CameraPreview` activity from `ApiDemos` has its own `Preview` `ViewGroup` that handles the aspect ratio, and there you need to reverse the aspect ratio for use in portrait:

```
    if (displayOrientation == 90
        || displayOrientation == 270) {
      previewWidth=mPreviewSize.height;
      previewHeight=mPreviewSize.width;
    }
    else {
      previewWidth=mPreviewSize.width;
      previewHeight=mPreviewSize.height;
    }
```

where `displayOrientation` is that same value (`90` and `270` being portrait and reverse-portrait respectively, and note that I haven't tried getting reverse-portrait or reverse-landscape to work, so there may be more tweaking required).

Third -- and one that I find infuriating -- you must start the preview before calling `setPictureSize()` on the `Camera.Parameters`. Otherwise, it's as if the aspect ratio of the *picture* is applied to the preview frames, screwing things up.

So I used to have code resembling the following:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
Camera.Size pictureSize=getHost().getPictureSize(parameters);

parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
parameters.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);
parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);

camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();
```

and that's wrong. What you really need is:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
Camera.Size pictureSize=getHost().getPictureSize(parameters);

parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);

camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();

parameters=camera.getParameters();
parameters.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width, pictureSize.height);
parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Without that change, I'd get a stretched aspect ratio, even in landscape. This wasn't a problem for `CameraPreview` of `ApiDemos`, as they were not taking pictures, and so they never called `setPictureSize()`.

But, so far, on a Nexus 4, I now have square aspect ratios for portrait and landscape, with a floating orientation (i.e., not locked to landscape).

I'll try to remember to amend this question if I run into other hacks required by other devices, plus to link to my `CameraView`/`CameraFragment` components when they are released.

---

**UPDATE #1**

Well, of course, it couldn't possibly by *nearly* this simple. :-)

The fix for the problem where `setPictureSize()` screws up the aspect ratio works... until you take a picture. At that point, the preview switches to the wrong aspect ratio.

One possibility would be to limit pictures to ones with the same (or very close) aspect ratio to the preview, so the hiccup does not exist. I don't like that answer, as the user should be able to get whatever picture size the camera offers.

You can limit the scope of the damage by:

- Only updating the picture size, etc. of the `Camera.Parameters` just before taking the picture
- Reverting to the pre-picture-taking `Camera.Parameters` after taking the picture

This still presents the wrong aspect ratio during the moments while the picture is being taken. The long-term solution for this -- I think -- will be to temporarily replace the camera preview with a still image (the last preview frame) while the picture is being taken. I'll try this eventually.

---

**UPDATE #2**: v0.0.1 of [my CWAC-Camera library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) is now available, incorporating the aforementioned code.

Comment: Wow, yeah either we're misunderstanding them, or the Camera APIs are really, really bad. The fact that the documentation for [`setDisplayOrientation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) includes code to determine the proper value (why not add this to the actual Android source instead of leaving it in a Javadoc?) kind of confirms that it's a mess. Thanks for the info. :)

Comment: Hi. great work! I am wonder if your app can also solve my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348614/make-a-surfaceview-larger-than-the-screen-fitting-a-camera-preview-to-a-surface/. I cannot test this using your code right now :(

Comment: @Paul: Yeah, I saw your question there, and I haven't a clue on it, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you so much for sharing this useful info and your time, **it helped me for setting picture size**, would you please guide me **how can set Camera preview in Portrait mode?**, I posted my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176038/camera-setdisplayorientation-function-is-not-working-for-samsung-galaxy-ace-wi but so far no luck.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I am pleasure invite you visit this page and take a look at my problem, thank you very much: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950044/setdisplayorientation-in-camera-make-wrong-orientation-when-save-image?noredirect=1#comment55660353_33950044

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys,
i was really going crazy the last two weeks about this f***** problem.
so okay, few things to know:

- sometimes you **just get black borders**, if actionbar or soft buttons are visible, just possible on some devices, **my advice:** **don't care** or you'll get crazy, or cut previews, both not good...

changes by @CommonsWare are just perfect, but cannot be applied directly to the CameraPreview from **API Level 8 Samples** (link below), so here is the **diff**:

**for correct aspect ratio in portrait do:**
methods are the same, just apply diff

```
public void setCamera(Camera camera, boolean portrait) {
    mCamera = camera;
    this.portrait = portrait;
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        requestLayout();
    }
}

public void switchCamera(Camera camera, boolean portrait) throws IOException {
   setCamera(camera, portrait);
   camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);       
   Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
   parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
   requestLayout();

   camera.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

in:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {…}
```

change:

```
int previewWidth = width;
int previewHeight = height;
if (mPreviewSize != null) {
      previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
      previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
}
```

**to:**

```
if (portrait && mPreviewSize != null) {
      previewWidth = mPreviewSize.height;
      previewHeight = mPreviewSize.width;
}
else if (mPreviewSize != null){
      previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
      previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
}
```

in:

```
private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {…}
```

change:

```
double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
```

**to:**

```
double targetRatio = 1;
if (portrait) {
    targetRatio= (double) w / h;
}
```

**finally starting camera for portrait mode with something like:**

```
try {
     mCamera = openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
     if (portraitMode) {
       mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
     }
     preview.setCamera(mCamera, portraitMode);
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     handleCameraUnavailable();
}
```

WUUHUUUU!
For me finally nor problems in preview, and no problems on saving images.
Because my location of activity is locked, i get the display orientation via OrientationChangedListener for saving images with correct orientation.

using something like: 
http://www.androidzeitgeist.com/2013/01/fixing-rotation-camera-picture.html

**But they are correctly previewed and saved.**

I hope I can help many people with that, there is the **original code from API Level 8**: 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.java
where the changes were applied.

Answer (score -1):

Please change the camera orientation on your code and you should `setDisplayorientation()` not `getDisplayOrientation()`

```
if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
{   
  camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);

}
```