# CWAC - Pink Camera Previews in bright screne

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

I was including CWAC-Android Library in my Project, at first, thanks a lot for doing this work.
But I experience some really strange problem.

Pictures in light scene (area, outside, bright light, beautiful day, sunlight), and images **get some pink overlay,**
on fast checking it i was not able to find a solution or a reason for that,
it seems it's just some overlay and not really "the image",

**it tried it in my implementation, 

and the library demo project, it exists in both .. :/**

im doing it on a xperia Z1? maybe another problem?

any assistance would be great?

Some sample images 
http://s1.directupload.net/images/140227/463xystc.jpg
http://s7.directupload.net/images/140227/l78xvjhd.jpg

sorry my mouth is always open on images :D ;) thanks
**Pictures taken with sample (demo) project**

Problem seems to occur when directly moving camera to bright "scene" and taking picture immediately, like this small amount of time when the camera screen is just overexposed

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I am not intentionally introducing a pink overlay, and there is no `setPinkOverlayEnabled(boolean)` method for you to use. :-) There may be some `Camera.Parameters` that you would need to tweak to address this. You might try building Focal from source and see if it exhibits the same problem, plus trying SONY's stock camera app and see if you can reproduce it there.

Comment: Looks a bit like out-of-gamut values being converted improperly.  Is there a color conversion going on?

Comment: hey ;) thanks a lot for the fast reponse, yeah, already tried it with sony stock software, no problem there, also on my own implementation before, there was no such problem, but image was distorted :( so i was really lucky (and happy) to find you library, i already checked complete CameraView, also checked if its maybe because of mirroring... btw. after your response i just checked -> problem seems to be just occuring on FFC :) maybe something different there u now?

Comment: @fadden Color conversion going on? dont know what you really mean? somehow it also looks like the real 'correct' image is below it, and it's just additionally on top, btw. can you see the small area on the left? -> http://s7.directupload.net/images/140227/7moru8th.png , dont know where it comes from, but sometimes it also seems to be there, but different issue. btw. sorry ;) professional picutre ;D

Comment: @fadden: I'm not doing any color correction in the library. At most, I rotate or flip the image, to standardize the output, using some `Matrix` transforms.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks again, i already checked the matrix conversions, disabling them brings no better result :(

Comment: @cV2: :: shrug :: If `ImageCleanupTask` is not doing any work, then you're getting what's straight off the `Camera`, and I *really* don't know what to tell you. Plus, I am out of the office for a bit. I have [filed an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/124) for this. If you don't mind, could you visit that issue and put in there the precise model and Android version of your device? I have no idea if I will be able to reproduce this, but I'd need those details to have a shot. Thanks!

Comment: If you look at l78xvjhd.jpg it actually seems to be bringing out detail in the image -- look at the window frame to the right of your head.  It's like something is doing a transformation on the pixels but screwing up the math in one channel.  At first glance there's a horizontal band of reasonable colors, but the clouds got pinked out in 463xystc.jpg even in that section.  If you want something else to try you can give Grafika's "Show + capture camera" a go (https://github.com/google/grafika, I don't currently have a ready-to-go APK).

Comment: @CommonsWare ready :) will do it immediately. if you need any any assistance to reproduce the problem: fast movement to bright area, press take picture on front camera (on my device) - 1 out of three pink (or more). Phone details added

Comment: @fadden thanks for your suggestions, belonging the other library, im api level 11+ :) so not possible, belonging your words about the pink overlay.. indeed. there must be some logic doin this ;)

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried to directly disable image cleanup task, but crashed ;) maybe i have to try it a more effort way then just commenting it ;) :P

Comment: sun is soon going down here, (GMT+1) so will have problems to reproducing it by myself ;)

Comment: i just disabled complete logic of ImageCleanupTask, just putting out straight the image data -> same poroblem -> but also interesting image ... http://s14.directupload.net/images/140227/ktydwny9.jpg

Comment: hey guyes, you won't believe this, changing from targetApi 17 to build against latest (19) android api -> pink changes to "bright" ... http://s7.directupload.net/images/140227/zi5nsujt.png

Comment: thanks a lot for the support!

Answer (score 0):

finally I **didn't find any solution** of the problem **within the library** to fix by myself,
did the implementation **on my own** (basic one) -> **works just fine.**

using following **fix for distortions** (portrait and lanscape):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22201580/371749

good luck