# Image Sized a little-bit to small, and ratio changes on rotation

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

using the cwac-camera library,
on the left and on the right (more times just on the left), the final image and the preview gets cut after taking a picture.

**Also Xperia Z1 -> FFC (Front Facing Camera) ->**
left and right side images are cut 
http://s7.directupload.net/images/140228/ei5saica.png
http://s14.directupload.net/images/140228/ftnecxau.png

**Another issue:**
Also I added the library's view into a fullscreen fragment which **will not be recreated** **on rotation** -> result -> somehow the **screen-preview-ratio changes** on 
- **portrait**

- **landscape**
- **and taking picture**

Means: On portrait the head is a littlebit wider (more width) than on landscape, and after taking picture the preview image is also a little bit more stretched then the (live) preview berfore. But finally the image seems to be the correct one.
This Problem was seen on an HTC One :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that StackOverflow is for programming questions. Nothing here is a question. If you feel that you have identified bugs, [post an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues) with **complete** steps to reproduce the problem, including device model(s) and Android OS version(s). Use StackOverflow for *questions* about the library.

> using the cwac-camera library, on the left and on the right (more times just on the left), the final image and the preview gets cut after taking a picture.

I would guess that it is a variation on [this issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/71).

> Another issue

Part of this is presumably the same issue. With respect to "the screen-preview-ratio changes on portrait/landscape", if you are not creating a new `CameraView`, and you have the camera locked to landscape, then I do not see where I would be changing the preview behavior on an orientation change.

Comment: sorry, absolutely correct (most cases), was really going crazy by camera issues f**** them all ..^^ ;) always think like, at least if someone else searches for the issue, there is somewhere to start. love stackoverflow! for me it's more like "solution finding platform" :) but finally did some own implementation (at least without that issues (pink and / or borders), which seems to work correct for portrait and landscape. thanks a lot for the support! http://stackoverflow.com/a/22201580/371749

Answer (score 0):

You may set preview size and picture size independently. But to achieve the best results, choose picture size that has same aspect ratio as your preview frame. E.g. for preview 640x480, you can use 3264x2448 picture. But if you use 1280x720 preview, you will be better served by a wide picture, e.g. 4128X2322.

Note that usually, the wide (16:9) format is achieved by essentially cropping a 4:3 picture.

Comment: thanks a lot, i think by default this all should have been working correct from the library.